# using jquery hide column heading when no data in column in interactive report oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

when no data in a column then hide that column heading in interactive report oracle apex by using jquery or javascript.

Comment: What if there's data in one row, but not another?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jquery or javascript, but some update of apex can change something and then that solution don't works anymore.
Look at this post https://www.apex-at-work.com/2012/10/hide-interactive-report-column-with.html

They explain how to do this in 2012, but now that solution don't works anymore. 
To do this you need to check the correct selectors in universal theme.

Instead of using jquery or javascript you can use "server side condition" of that column. In that place you can do some query to check if that column should be visible or not.

Of course, depending on the query, the report load time may increase.